# Question with Dirichlet convolution involving Mobius function and divisor function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, dirichlet-series

So my question is:

Use the Dirichlet series to show that

$\sum_{k|n}\mu(k)d(\frac{n}{k})$ = 1

for all natural numbers n where d(.) is the divisor function.

I've just started learning about the Dirichlet convolution and I gather that

$\sum_{k|n}\mu(k)d(\frac{n}{k})$ = $\mu$ $\star$ d (n) = $\sum_{k|n}\mu(\frac{n}{k})d(k)$
but I don't know how to use that to prove that the LHS = 1

Comment: The divisor function is multiplicative and the moebius function is as well.  What about their convolution?  Would that help you get started on the LHS?

Comment: Do you know the Moebius inversion formula?  If so, note that $d(n) = \sum_{d | n} 1.$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I very recently learned the Mobius Inversion formula and hadn't thought of using it.
So using the MIF I can say d(n) = $\sum_{k|n} 1$ so here f(n) = 1 and g(n) = d(n), this means 
1 = $\sum_{k|n}\mu (k)d(\frac {n}{k})$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

We can write
$$
\sum_{k|n}\mu(k)d\left(\frac{n}{k}\right) = \mu *d
$$
where $*$ is Dirichlet convolution. The Dirichlet series of $\mu(n)$ is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}
$$
The Dirichlet series of $d(n)$ is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d(n)}{n^s} = \zeta(s)^2
$$
the convolution of the two is given by the product of their series
$$
\mu * d = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\cdot \zeta(s)^2 =\zeta(s)
$$
and $\zeta(s)$ is the Dirichlet series for $1$
$$
\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}
$$
thus 
$$
 \mu *d = \sum_{k|n}\mu(k)d\left(\frac{n}{k}\right) = 1
$$